# How to get a direct download of alternative flash player for Ubuntu (Adobe page launches Ubuntu Software Centre which reports 'file not found')

Tags: 14.04, sound, software-center, video, flash

To be frank, this page is useless:
http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/

Clicking download causes Ubuntu Software Centre to be launched which reports file not found.

Frustrating. So how can I get a direct file download of the flash player?

I would like this as I'm having the video playing too fast problem see by a few others around here and elsewhere and the alternative flash may solve the issue.

Hardware:
ASRock 775 G31M-GS R2.0 Motherboard Intel Socket M-ATX 1333FSB (with internal audio)
R700 Audio Device [Radeon HD 4000 Series]

Answer (score 0):

Remove the alternative plugin first

```
apt-get remove flashplugin-installer
```

You can download the adobe flash plugin directly from here (64 bit version) type at the terminal:

```
wget -c http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flashplugin_11.2.202.406-0trusty1_amd64.deb
```

or (32 bit version)

```
wget -c http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flashplugin_11.2.202.400-0trusty1_i386.deb
```

To install

```
sudo dpkg -i adobe-flashplugin*
```

Alternatively, you can enable in Software Center under Edit -> Software Sources... -> Other Software Tab, and select Canonical Partners. Then you can search and install it.

Comment: Didn't work - have you tried it yourself? (also tried via sw centre as you suggest, conflicts there too.)

`rob@medionubuntu:~$ sudo dpkg -i adobe-flashplugin*
dpkg: regarding adobe-flashplugin_11.2.202.400-0trusty1_amd64.deb containing adobe-flashplugin:
 adobe-flashplugin conflicts with flashplugin-installer
  flashplugin-installer (version 11.2.202.400ubuntu0.14.04.1) is present and installed.

dpkg: error processing archive adobe-flashplugin_11.2.202.400-0trusty1_amd64.deb (--install):
 conflicting packages - not installing adobe-flashplugin
Errors were encountered while processing:
 adobe

Comment: Yes it works. Just remove the alternative plugin first using `sudo apt-get remove flashplugin-installer`